# 64 bit ubuntu installation fails Dell XPS | 15Z

Tags: installation, dell

I tried to install 64 bit ubuntu desktop to the machine I stated above. When I try to do so by CD, the screen freezes, and when I try to do so using USB drive, the screen freezes again just after the line : [Firmware Bug] ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS

Is there anyway I can overcome this problem ?

ps: Installation procedure starts and works fine on other machines using the same CD and USB drive

Answer (score 3):

For everyone else getting this problem. Do not use acpi=off you better use acpi=noirq instead.

Answer (score 1):

When booting the CD/USB you see a purple screen with a keyboard icon in the bottom center. When this screen appear just **press any key (like the arrow keys)** from the keyboard once in order to make appear all the options.

Then **press F6** and selection **nomodeset**. And try to install it like that.

Comment: don't do `acpi=off`. It could be destructive. use `nomodeset`. use `acpi=off` as last resort. @aliasbosy, please edit it. read here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

Comment: Oops :S My fault, you are totally right :S I will edit then !

Comment: Please go through the link , if `nomodeset` doesn't work. Just use instruction in the link , look for option `acpi_osi`

Comment: I have tried everyone of them and only acpi=off works for me however, it is mentioned that this option might be risky, do you have any other suggestions for me ?

Comment: I don't know if the bug has been fixed in the newest versions of the kernel tho... But just in case, try to install with the "acpi=off" option since it works, and then after the instalation, try to start ubuntu normally, if it doesn't work, try with nomodeset, if it doesn't work, try with acpi_osi, if it still doesn't work, then try with acpi=off and fully update ubuntu (it will install the new kernel), then restart and boot normally and see if it worked.

Comment: installing 13.04 and using the nomodeset worked for me.